# can I use jQuery for iPhone development

Tags: jquery, iphone

I would like to know if I can use jQuery for the development of an iPhone app?
If yes then please provide link or examples.

Also, will Apple approve the app if it uses jQuery?

Comment: Yes, you can do **anything** with jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

- jQuery Mobile (or [jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com/)):
  http://jquerymobile.com/
- PhoneGap:
  http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 2):

See:

- http://jquerymobile.com/
- http://jqtouch.com/
- http://www.phonegap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for web development on the iPhone and other mobile devices. @NeXXeus and @Ryan Bates had good answers, above.

However if you want to write native iPhone apps, you'll either have to go through Apple's development process for your app. This may include, but is not limited to, learning and programming in Objective-C, using the XCode development environment on a Mac, and registering for and purchasing a developer license from Apple.